# Javascript function indexOf returns incorrect results

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, integer, indexof

I have these two arrays:

```
array1 = ["a,1", "b,2", "c3", "d4", "e5", "f6"];
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

And I'm trying to find out if an element of the first array is in the second one.

```
for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) { 
  if(array2.indexOf(array1[i][1]) != -1) {
    console.log('In array: '+array1[i][1]);
  } else {
    console.log('NOT in array: '+array1[i][1]);
}
```

In this case, I always get the message **NOT in array ..**.

But if I modify the code this way:

```
for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) { 
  if(array2.indexOf(1) != -1) {
    console.log('In array: '+array1[i][1]);
  } else {
    console.log('NOT in array: '+array1[i][1]);
}
```

The output is **In array: ...**.

With a number as a parameter of the **indexOf()** function it's working, but no with the variable... how is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: `array1[i][1]` is `","` or `undefined`, depending on the browser.

Comment: You're comparing a string to a number, so they'll never match. Your `+` fixes that issue. I assume the `[1]` index is mistaken in your working example.

Comment: `"3"` is not the same as `3`, and `","` is definitely not the same as `1`.

Comment: [*indexOf*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.14) uses a strict comparison and accessing strings by index is not supported by all browsers in use, perhaps you need `array2.indexOf(Number(array1[i].split(',')[1]))`, but not all members in *array1* use a comma separator.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
if(array2.indexOf(array1[i][1]) != -1) {
```

is comparing a string to a number using strict comparison per the algorithm for [*indexOf*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.14). Also, in most cases you are comparing the wrong character from *array1*. In:

```
"a,1"
```

character 1 is the comma, not the number. What you need to do is get the numbers from the strings in *array1*, convert them to number type so *indexOf* works using an expression like:

```
+array1[i].replace(/\D/g,'')
```

then do the comparison, e.g.:

```
array1 = ["a,1", "b,2", "c3", "d4", "e5", "f6"];
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];


for (var i=0, iLen=array1.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (array2.indexOf(+array1[i].replace(/\D/g,'')) != -1) {
        console.log('In array: ' + array1[i]);
    } else {
        console.log('Not in array: ' + array1[i]);
    }
}

// In array: a,1
// In array: b,2
// In array: c3
// In array: d4
// Not in array: e5
// Not in array: f6
```

You may need to modify the regular expression getting the numbers depending on the full range of strings that might be in *array1*.

An alternative is to convert the members of *array2* to strings and search for them in the members of *array1*.